# Extending form validation doesn't work - overriding works

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've an interesting state in my **form validation extension** in CI. I've created a `MY_Form_validation.php` Class. This class **is automatically instantiated** (tried with output in constructor) AND **method overriding also works**. E.g. if I add the method `required` to the new class, it works like a charm.

BUT: New methods (like `valid_true_false` or `valid_vat_id`) added to `MY_Form_validation` class are completely ignored.

I've no more idea what the reason could be. It could not be a naming convention issue, because **method overloading works**.

Here is my class:

```
/**
 * CodeIgniter Form Validation Extension
 */
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function __construct( $config = array() )
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    // WORKS
    function required($str)
    {
        echo 'required check';
        return false;
    }

    // DOESN´T WORK
    function test() {
        die('TEST');
    }

    // DOESN´T WORK
    function valid_true_false($input){
        die('truefalse');
        return ( ! preg_match("/^(true|false|0|1)$/", $input)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    // DOESN´T WORK
    function valid_vat_id() {
        die('VALIDATING VAT ID');
        return false;
    }


}
```

Maybe anyone has an idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

OMG... It was simply a test-case problem.
If you **leave the field empty**, the **validation method isn´t called at all**. So you have to add any content in the field that it get´s validated. Maybe somebody makes the same mistake like me in the future :)

Comment: Hi there! This was the exact same problem I am having from the past 4 hours and searched the web extensively until I reached this post. Thanks for posting your experience. Apart from that, how foolish is it of CI to completely ignore a form validation method if the field is empty. After all if you put a validation function instead of required you've put it there for a reason, haven't you? That practice seems totally unintuitive on CI part. I'm a big fan of CI but these things make it look immature.